# Tesseract __init__.py throws an error

Tags: python

I am trying to pass recahptca using tesseract in python.
On doing that, following error gets displayed:

```
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\tesseract\__init__.py", line 34
      print 'Creating user config file: {}'.format(_config_file_usr)
                                    ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the issue here?

[Edit]

This is the code that I have:

```
import ConfigParser
import os import shutil
# Initialize config file
config_file_def = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(_file),"default_config.ini")
_config_file_usr = os.path.expanduser("~/.tessrc")
if not os.path.isfile(_config_file_usr): 
print 'Creating user config file: {}'.format(_config_file_usr) 
shutil.copyfile(_config_file_def,_config_file_usr)
```

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: it will be useful if you give the code too (the lines where the error number points to)

Comment: __init_.py file is follow.

import ConfigParser
import os
import shutil

# Initialize config file
_config_file_def = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"default_config.ini")
_config_file_usr = os.path.expanduser("~/.tessrc")
if not os.path.isfile(_config_file_usr):
    print 'Creating user config file: {}'.format(_config_file_usr)
    shutil.copyfile(_config_file_def,_config_file_usr)

Comment: my python version is 3.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like Python 2.7.x code. Either change your python version to 2.7.x or try to migrate your code and dependencies so it can be interpreted by Python 3.x.

The notable difference here is that Python 3.x won't allow this kind of pseudo-functions:

`print 'Foobar'`

It will fail to recognize it as a valid syntax and that is more likely causing the issues you are having.

Python 3 will expect you to use `print('Foobar')` instead.

Comment: You are welcome! If the answer addresses the issue, please mark it as accepted so it can appear as answered in the question stack.